Comparing the number Latin squares of order $4$ and Latin squares of order $5$ where the first row is fixed
This question was given to one of my high school student friends. Compare the number of Latin squares of order $4$ and Latin squares of order $5$ where the first row is fixed, and determine which one is greater and by how much. It's a shame I cannot solve this question given to a high school student as a graduate. I just thought we would simply find an injection or surjection, but I couldn't embed one into the other easily.

According to Wikipedia, there are $576$ Latin squares of order $4$,  so $576/4!=24$ where the first row is fixed, and there are $161,280/5!=1344$ Latin squares of order $5$ with the first row fixed. I do not think there is a shortcut to solve this; you need to count all Latin squares of orders $4$ and $5$, which is hard.

We also need to compute the difference of the two numbers, so an injection is not useful. To start, consider the reduction that makes the first column also ordered, Latin square wiki link. We first count such reduced squares. If only the first row in an $n\times n$ Latin square is known to be reduced, then use the permutation of the entries in the first column that makes it the reduced, ordered column. Let $a(n), r(n)$ be the number of Latin squares where the first row, respectively both first row and first column appear in the natural order. Then $a(n)=(n-1)!\cdot r(n)$. Let us compute $r(4)$ and $r(5)$, we expect to obtain the values $r(4)=4$, and $r(5)=56$, as in the mentioned wiki link.

The case $n=4$. The first row, resp. column is set. In a picture:
    1 2 3 4
    2 X ? ?
    3 ? ? ?
    4 ? ? ?

We have three possible values on the position $X$. If $X=1$, then second line and column are set. The remained $2\times 2$ subsquare has two chances
    1 2     2 1
    2 1     1 2

so we obtain two solutions. Else $X$ is either $3$ or $4$. And we have unique completions after this decision, first on the second row/column, then for the remained $1$-entry, then for the rest:
    1 2 3 4        1 2 3 4
    2 3 4 1        2 4 1 3
    3 4 1 2        3 1 4 2
    4 1 2 3        4 3 2 1

So there are in total $r(4)$ expected reduced Latin squares. This explicit example shows the following idea in its second case. The decision $X=3$ leads to a set of solutions. For each such solution switch $3\leftrightarrow 4$. We obtain solutions with first row/column normed to $1,2,4,3$ instead, which is bijectively rearranged in reduced form. This operation is used in similar fashion below.


The case $n=5$. We start with
    1 2 3 4 5
    2 X ? ? ?
    3 ? ? ? ?
    4 ? ? ? ?
    5 ? ? ? ?

and have for the position $X$ to cases. If $X=1$, we have one subcase, for $X=3,4,5$ we have one and the same subcase by the mentioned switch argument.

We count first using the decision $X=1$. The position $Y$ below
    1 2 3 4 5
    2 1 Y ? ?
    3 ? ? ? ?
    4 ? ? ? ?
    5 ? ? ? ?

has two chances, and by the switch argument we may and do assume $Y=4$, then double the number of the resulted solutions to cover both $Y=4,5$. We have so far:
    1 2 3 4 5
    2 1 4 5 3
    3 Z ? ? ?
    4 ? ? ? ?
    5 ? ? ? ?

Now for the $Z$ position we have to consider both possibilities, so the enumeration ramifies:
    1 2 3 4 5        1 2 3 4 5
    2 1 4 5 3        2 1 4 5 3
    3 4 ? ? ?        3 5 ? ? ?
    4 5 ? ? ?        4 3 ? ? ?
    5 3 ? ? ?        5 4 ? ? ?

We fill in the positions of $3,4,5$ in the $3\times 3$ subsquare:
    1 2 3 4 5        1 2 3 4 5
    2 1 4 5 3        2 1 4 5 3
    3 4 5 ? ?        3 5 ? ? 4
    4 5 ? 3 ?        4 3 5 ? ?
    5 3 ? ? 4        5 4 ? 3 ?

For the first $?$ in the third row there are two possibilities, $1,2$. Once made a decision $Z$ the other two places for $Z$ in the next rows are determined, and this determines the final placement of the non-$Z$ value. So we obtain four solutions. Times two for the $Y$-decision, there are eight solutions.

The other subcase starts with the situation $X\ne 1$,
and we can and do assume $X=3$, finally multiplying by the factor three. Then we have further decisions for the open positions near this $X$. So we split into the cases:
    1  2  3  4  5   (A)      1  2  3  4  5    (B)
    2  3  1  5  4            2  3  4* 5  1    4* is chosen, 5* case is similar
    3  1  ?? ?  ?            3  1  ?  ?  ?
    4  5  ?  ?  ?            4  5  ?  ?  ? 
    5  4  ?  ?  ?            5  4  ?  ?  ?

    1  2  3  4  5   (B')     1  2  3  4  5    (C)
    2  3  1  5  4            2  3  4* 5  1    4* is chosen, 5* is case similar
    3  4  ?  ?  ?            3  4  ?  ?  ?
    4  5  ?  ?  ?            4  5  ?  ?  ? 
    5  1  ?  ?  ?            5  1  ?  ?  ?

    1  2  3  4  5   (B'')    1  2  3  4  5    (D)
    2  3  1  5  4            2  3  4* 5  1    4* is chosen, 5* case similar
    3  5  ?  ?  ?            3  5  ?  ?  ?
    4  1  ?  ?  ?            4  1  ?  ?  ? 
    5  4  ?  ?  ?            5  4  ?  ?  ?

We may used also diagonal symmetries as for the cases $(B)$ and $(B')$. Also the cases $(B')$ and $(B'')$ are similar. In case $(A)$ the position $??$ must be occupied by both $4,5$, no completion to a solution. It is enough to focus on the cases $(B)$, $(C)$, $(D)$. We fill in the determined places:
                1  2  3  4  5    (B)
                2  3  4* 5  1
                3  1  5  2  4
                4  5  ?  ?  ? 
                5  4  ?  ?  ?

                1  2  3  4  5    (C)
                2  3  4* 5  1
                3  4  5  1  2
                4  5  1  2  3 
                5  1  2  3  4

                1  2  3  4  5    (D)
                2  3  4* 5  1
                3  5  ?  ?  4
                4  1  5  ?  ? 
                5  4  ?  ?  ?

Now we check the possibilities to fill in the squares. For $(B)$ there are two ways, the choice of places of $1,2$ on the third column determine the final state. For $(C)$ everything is already determined. One solution. For $(D)$ we have again two possibilities for the last column. If we put $5,1,4,2,3$ on this column then the fourth row is also fixed, the remained $2\times 2$ empty submatrix has two chances using the values $1,2$ in different order in the two lines or columns. If we put instead  $5,1,4,3,2$ on this column then the fourth row is also fixed, uses a $2$ at a place that determines all other entries. So we count in total:
(A)   --> 0               (B) 2 for 4*, 2 for 5*

(B')  --> 2 as for (B)    (C) 1 for 4*, 1 for 5*

(B'') --> 2 as for (B)    (D) 2+1 for 4*, 2+1 for 5*
        

So there are $16$ such latin squares constructed by starting with a $3$ on the following position X:
1 2 3 4 5
2 X ? ? ?
3 ? ? ? ?
4 ? ? ? ?
5 ? ? ? ?

For each choice of $X$ among $3,4,5$ we have same number of solutions.
So there are $3\cdot 16=48$ Latin squares with $X=3,4,5$.

Putting all together we have $8$ solutions in the case $X=1$, $48$ solutions in the remaining case $X=3,4,5$, so $r(5)=8+48=56$, as the wiki informs us.
As mentioned at the beginning, if only the first row is reduced, then the remaining rows can be permuted to deliver other solutions, and each other solution becomes reduced (also on first column) when a right permutation of rows (corresponding to the entries in the first column) is chosen. So the OP question wants the numbers:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(4-1)!\cdot r(4) &= 3!\cdot 4=24\ ,\\
(5-1)!\cdot r(5) &= 4!\cdot 56 = 1344\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(The difference $1344-24=1320$ has no structural meaning, from my point of view.)
